# What will happen to our solar system if the milky way collided with Andromeda galaxy, would any planets survive?

Tags: galaxy

Is there a chance if any planets in our solar system survive when the milky way and Andromeda collide?

Comment: This question is different, it asks for what happens to the solar system, not whether life could survive or about prospective space travel.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Their is a very poor chance of survival for us, but we might survive for a little longer if it hits from the opposite direction form us, but then again, humans will probably be extinct  by then. Also, try to have more detail in your questions.

Comment: A collision of the Milky Way and Andromeda galaxies would have very little direct effect on the Solar System. Why do you think otherwise? Or are you referring to the fact that the Sun will have expanded by then? If so, you need to be clearer.

Comment: I would also suggest looking at the possible duplicate question I gave above. Excellent points by Keith.